# Automate VM backup to trigger once every 6 months

Tags: azure, azure-vm, azure-backup

I have a Windows test server, and I want to have its backup for last six months. Like have a full backup of the server once in six month and retain it. In azure backup policy I can't see any option for monthly backup frequency. So is there any other way to achieve this? like snapshots of the disks?

Any I want it to be automated. Open for all opinions.

Comment: You can use backup software.

Answer (score 0):

Veeam Backup Community Edition. It's free for under 10 resources.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I will check this out too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/574908)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not completely answer the question but Azure Backup has long term backup. Im sure there is an option to store it 6 months

Here is an PowerShell script to  configure that

```
    # Connect to Azure account
Connect-AzAccount

# Define variables
$ResourceGroupName = "YourResourceGroup"
$BackupVaultName = "YourBackupVault"
$BackupPolicyName = "MonthlyBackupPolicy"
$RetentionPeriodInDays = 183  # 6 months

# Create the backup policy
$BackupPolicy = New-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $BackupPolicyName `
    -WorkloadType AzureVM `
    -RetentionDuration $RetentionPeriodInDays `
    -ScheduleRunFrequency Monthly `
    -ScheduleRunDays @(1)  # Run on the first day of every month

# Set the backup policy for Azure VMs
$AzureVMs = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM
foreach ($VM in $AzureVMs) {
    Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -Name $BackupVaultName `
        -AzureVM $VM `
        -Policy $BackupPolicy
}
```

This configures a monthly backup at the first of the month and keeps the backup for 6 months. And attaches the VMs to the backup policy

And you can extend it with an automation runbook that newly deployed VMs are automatically associated with the backup policy or an azure policy. If you want me to elaborate about that let me know

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. I haven't tried using powershell till now I was using the portal and there I was not able to find such option in schedule. Let me try using this.